# why wont javascript "checkbox.disable" grey out associated label in ASP.NET?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, checkbox

I'm using some javascript to disable the checkboxes in a checkboxlist like so:

```
        var objItem = document.getElementById("<%= resCBL.ClientID %>");
        var checkBoxes = objItem.getElementsByTagName("input");

        if (form1.secTB.value == 0) {
            checkBoxes[0].disabled = true;
```

This code works fine, but when the page renders in IE, the text attribute for the checkbox is rendered as a label, and so only the checkbox seems to grey out, instead of the checkbox AND the text.

If I simply set

```
Enabled = false
```

in the .aspx codebehind, it greys out everything, but makes it impossible (with my current method) to re-enable the CB and un-grey the label.

Could anyone tell me how to work around this and help me understand why it's doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the HTML output from a checkbox control you'll see there is an associated `<label for="checkbox_client_id">Text</label>` - this is why setting the checkbox as disabled doesn't grey-out the text.

When viewing the page from IE, ASP.NET wraps the `<input>` and associated `<label>` with `<span disabled="disabled">`.  IE will disable all elements inside the span, which is why it disabled the checkbox and label.

However, since a span is not a form element, most other browsers follow the [W3C rules](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp) and ignore the "disabled" attribute it.  Disabling a span around the checkbox will only work in IE.

The easiest solution I can think of is to replicate this behavior manually.  Wrap the checkbox with a span then, when enabling/disabling the checkbox use CSS to style the span and get the desired effect to work on all browsers.

```
var objItem = document.getElementById("<%= resCBL.ClientID %>");
var checkBoxes = objItem.getElementsByTagName("input");

if (form1.secTB.value == 0) {
    checkBoxes[0].disabled = true;
    checkBoxes[0].parentNode.class = "disabled";
}
```

P.S. Sorry if I sound snarky - IE always annoys me with it's endless "intricacies"

Comment: This is also an excellent solution to the above problem. Definitely didn't sound snarky - I find the IE 'gotchas' to be quite frustrating as well, and much prefer the W3C standards.

Comment: As an update, note that IE10 and up doesn't gray the label, even if the input inside the `<span disabled>` still gets disabled itself.

Answer (score 4):

Add the disabled attribute  to the [`InputAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.inputattributes.aspx) of the `CheckBox` instead:

```
CheckBox1.InputAttributes.Add("disabled", "disabled");
```

http://geekswithblogs.net/jonasb/archive/2006/07/27/86498.aspx

The problem is that an `<asp:checkbox />` control gets rendered out like this:

```
<span><input type='checkbox'></span>
```

The real problem comes when you have a checkbox like this: `<asp:CheckBox Enabled="false"/>`.

This gets rendered out like this:

```
<span disabled='disabled'><input type='checkbox' disabled='disabled'></span>
```

Comment: MyCheckBox.disabled = false;
MyCheckBox.parentNode.disabled = false; also works quite well, as mentioned in the comments.   Curious why it renders like this? seems like a fairly obvious problem...